# Howto use the Silverlight Toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to implement a Drag and Drop interface for my windows phone application. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/20/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx). I have downloaded and installed the Silverlight toolkit from [their](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) site. Also I have added a reference to it.

I get the following error when I try to compile my code.

```
Error   1   'toolkit' is an undeclared prefix. Line 33, position 14.    C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DragEventDemo\DragEventDemo\MainPage.xaml   33  14  DragEventDemo
```

This is the code I have in the content grid in my MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="OnDragDelta"
        GestureBegin="OnGestureBegin" GestureCompleted="OnGestureCompleted" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

What am I missing out on?

Comment: Have you included the Toolkit namespace in the page?

`xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you got a prefix declaration within your PhoneApplicationPage tag?

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
        (...)
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
        (...) 
    >
```

Comment: How do I get this to add automatically?

Comment: There are extentions that help with that, eg. Resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/